# Rustlang deku generic type

Tags: parsing, rust

I am currently working with Rust and the [deku](https://github.com/sharksforarms/deku/tree/master) crate and face an optimization issue.
The task is quite simple, I would like to parse some binary data into into a Rust struct.

My code is this:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, DekuRead)]
pub struct EntryU32 {
    id: u8,
    value: u32,
}
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq, DekuRead)]

pub struct EntryU16 {
    id: u8,
    value: u16,
}
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, DekuRead)]
pub struct BinData {
    entry1: EntryU32,
    entry2: EntryU16,
}
// which allows me to parse the binary via BinData::from_bytes(...)
```

But this approach requires a dedicated `EntryStruct` for each datatype → `u8`, `i8`, `u16`, …
So I would like to use a generic one, something like the following one:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, DekuRead)]
pub struct Entry<T> {
    id: u8,
    value: T,
}
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, DekuRead)]
pub struct BinData {
    entry1: Entry::<u32>,
    entry2: Entry::<u32>,
}
```

But this raises the error, that `DekuRead` is not implemented for type `T`.
Full error message:

```
the trait bound `T: deku::DekuRead<'_, _>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `deku::DekuRead<'a, Ctx>`:
  <bool as deku::DekuRead<'a, Ctx>>
  <isize as deku::DekuRead<'_, (Endian, deku::ctx::ByteSize)>>
```

I am not sure how to scope the datatype `T` such that `DekuRead` (and later `DekuWrite`) works properly. I have tried to bound it as shown below, but I currently bounds from one type of error to the other one.

```
pub struct Entry<T>
where
    T: DekuRead<'a>,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where you need a higher ranked trait bound [(HRTB)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, DekuRead)]
pub struct Entry<T>
where T: for<'a> DekuRead<'a>,
{
    id: u8,
    value: T,
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to insert the constraint into the derived `DekuRead` impl? Putting it on the struct ain't good.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I agree, but the derive needs it. If you implement `DekuRead` by hand probably.